# Show that adding a series capacitor of value C = 1/(w x L) makes the power factor equal 1 in a series RL circuit

Tags: power, passive-networks

Show that the power factor is equal to 1 when C = 1/WL in an RLC circuit.

I've had some problems finding out how to prove this, and I found a similiar solution online.

[image]

I have some problems understanding most of the steps. When the person finds the phasor current, I understand that he multiplies the complex conjugate on nominator and deminator.

As far as I can understand, after that he multiplies V with the phasor current, and he finds the real numbers of V*I. What I don't understand is what the person does after that.

For me it seems like he doesn't do anything wit the real number he found out of V*I, instead he takes the square root of complex conjugate in the nominator, and it just a mess after that.

Does anyone understand the steps after that, or do someone have an easier way to solve this probem? Worst case scenario, can someone provide me with the resources so I can understand the math behind this? My math is a bit rusty.

Comment: You can solve this far more easily with phasors. Answer this question for yourself: "What is the phase between voltage and current at a power factor of 1?"

Comment: Since P = S * cos (θ) and P = S in this case, where θ is the phase angle between the current and voltage, then the phase angle must be 90 degrees.

Comment: The power factor is the *cosine* of the phase angle. Cosine 90 is 0.

Comment: Yes, I mixed up. So the phase angle should be 0 then. cos(0) = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Show that the power factor is equal to 1 when C = 1/WL in an RLC
> circuit.*

Well, you seem to be going down a mathematical route that isn't yielding you the answer you want. Quite simple, for a series tuned circuit at resonance (that also means a power factor of unity): -

$$|X_C| = |X_L|$$

Or, put another way, \$\dfrac{1}{j\omega C} = -j\omega L\$

Therefore, \$1 = \omega^2 LC\hspace{2cm}\$ or \$\hspace{2cm}C = \dfrac{1}{\omega^2 L}\$

So basically your original formula is incorrect because it needs an \$\omega^2\$ term. Or maybe you left that term from your title because in your scribbled notes you appear to say it: -

[image]

Comment: I get it now. When Xc = XL, then C = ((1/(W^2)*L). Since Xc = XL they cancel each other out and Z = R. Since P = True power = (I^2) * R , and S = Apparent power = (I^2) * Z they will have the same value. Much simpler than going through a mathematical rabbit hole.